# Odd problem I keep having, wondering if its because I use types with same name as namespace?

Tags: c#, reference

**UPDATE:**

I ended up solving this in a way I did not expect - it apparently was not the namespace/typename collision I thought it was (to my surprise when I re-did it and it failed the exact same way).  I *think* maybe this is minor VS bug - here's what happened:

**--> The error path**

- I added a Winforms project
- I added a reference to Lib1
- Lib1 appeared as an added reference
- (I revise my estimate of exactly when VS gets "confused") The next time I compile, things get broken and it's as if I never added the reference to Lib1.

**--> Surprising way I ended up resolving the issue:**

- I was taking random shots because I was confused and I decided to add the library a (slightly) different way.
- Instead of right clicking the References node in the Solution Explorer and choosing Lib1 from the "solutions" tab, I chose it from the "Recent" tab.
- When I added it, to my surprise, VS complained that *it could not add the library*
- The reason was my Library was set to .NET 4 and my Winforms app defaulted to Client profile.

**--> the issue was resolved when I switched my winforms app to .NET 4**

Background/Motivation:

I'm a lone developer - which is why when I have strangnesses like this one, I sometimes spend 20 minutes and if I can't figure it out I completely work around it.  Sometimes these problems recur, and I spend another 20 minutes, and become annoyed with the workaround a second time, which finally makes me really want to figure it out.  This is the case now.

Description of the Problem:

I'm coding along, in this case, I was prototyping an ASP.NET website with VS10.

- new project, ASP.NET website: Web1 (creates solution)
- add Project, C# library, Lib1 (adds to solution)
- Lib1: add Model.cs, View.cs, Presenter.cs, ...etc
- Web1: add a DataList to Default.aspx, bind data via Lib1
- Test it it works

---> Now I want to see my Lib1 work for a winforms project, basically proving to myself I can write Library code that doesn't care about the UI

- add Project, WinformsApp1 (adds to solution)
- add a DataGridView to Form1, bind data via Lib1

Then the wierdest thing happend (at least to me): At first, adding a reference to Lib1 and implementing the IView interface on Form1 works fine, but as soon as VS auto populates the stubs for IView, everything goes to a state as if I didn't add the reference to Lib1.  That is, the compiler tells me it doesn't know the definition of IView, and politely reminds me that I might have forgotten to add a reference, but the kicker is that it's talking about the code that it just generated and would not have been able to without that reference.

NOTE: If nobody knows just what this is and I'm wrong that this is a symptom of lone developer syndrome, I'll work up the example again and post the code (I just zapped it).

Comment: So can the code compile?

Comment: Nope, I basically gave up and made a copy of Lib1 for me Winforms project, which is bad workaround

Comment: Worth reading, since you mention namespace and type naming: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/namespaces/

Comment: i'm starting to feel like i should devote a couple of weeks to reading all that guy's posts :)

Comment: @Anthony, i think you nailed it - if you put it as the answer i'll mark it.

Comment: If you continue to have a problem, you should follow through and post a small version of the code that reproduces the error, if you can. Also, I would edit the question text to include what's relevant, not a particular backstory (although I certainly empathize with a lone developer situation, as I've been there before).

Comment: @Gabriel, I'll let the comment suffice. If anyone (yourself included) wants to expand upon the linked information and turn it into a full answer, feel free!

Comment: Have you tried moving all your 'using' statements inside your namespaces? While this is a subtle difference, it can sometimes create problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a method in your interface that has the same name as the namespace, so when you populated the interface the compiler could no longer differentiate between the namespace and the method.